# Notes 901 Install on El Capitan not launching

Tags: macos, installation, lotus-notes

I have a mac user who recently upgraded to El Capitan.  We've been trying to install Notes on her machine.  It installs but when we try and launch it, a window comes up saying that Notes is starting 'please wait' then just closes and nothing happens.  I called IBM support but they have not been able to figure this out.  They had me look for a 'preferences' file which should be in the Library folder (they say) but that apparently is not getting created.  I was able to find a Data directory in 'IBM Notes > Contents>Resources>English.iproj>Data' and it is populated with a bunch of templates so it does seem to be getting installed.  The user has admin privs on the machine.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

thanks!

clem

Comment: I have OSx El Capitan 10.11.3 and am running the Notes Client with limited issues. You do have to install the Java 6 packagefor it to work since Notes is stuck with an old version of Java. Might be better to ask this at: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: Old files that were not removed by the uninstaller were apparently causing the problem.  I deleted the Notes folder then the install went ahead.  It complained about not having the names.nsf file but I retrieved it from the trash and it worked.

clem